# How to run Chkdsk on all drives at startup on Windows Server 2003R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, boot, chkdsk

I am struggling to find a way to automate chkdsk /f on **all drives** at startup, as so far I couldn't accomplish this task.

1. Cannot use chkdsk in a batch file, as it would require user intervention (Y/N prompts in case of locked volumes).
2. The "fsutil dirty set " method will not work completely, only the c: drive check will be executed at startup

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: To verify disk state, weekly

Comment: I've never heard of anyone ever running chkdsk as a preventive maintenance measure.

Comment: Don't you ever scan your disks for faulty file system? Once a week seems reasonable to me...

Comment: Have I ever run it? Yes. Have I done it on a regular schedule as part of a preventive maintenance plan? No. Has anyone else? It's doubtful.

Comment: He needs to do it because he's still running Win2k3 on hardware. Not that that is a good scenario for anyone, mind you.

Comment: @mfinni, do newer Windows Server versions offer other techniques for filesystem integrity check

Comment: Newer operating systems are typically on virtualized hardware.

Comment: Yes, but virtualization will not prevent errors in the filesystem, mainly due to operating system failure or system "glitches", thus a regular filesystem check schedule should be mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I use this utility: [chkdskall](http://therightstuff.de/2009/02/14/ChkDskAll-ChkDsk-For-All-Drives.aspx)
2. You can use chkdsk in a batch file by echoing the Y and piping it to chkdsk as follows:

   `echo Y | chkdsk c: /f`

Comment: 1) I have tried chkdskall utility, however at boot time it won't check all disks
2) Firstly, not all prompts are the same, (for example as for c: drive the only prompt will be about possibility to schedule a check at next boot. while on other locked drives the first prompt will ask to forcibly dismount the disk + a second prompt to schedule at next boot), secondly, locked disks will be checked at reboot, while unlocked units will be checked immediately. Unsuitable

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which drives does chkdskall not check?

Comment: When I run chkdskall I get something like this:
Drive A:\ (Type Removable): No fixed drive, skipping.
Drive C:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk successfully scheduled.
Drive D:\ (Type CDRom): No fixed drive, skipping.
Drive E:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk successfully scheduled.
Drive F:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk successfully scheduled.
Drive R:\ (Type Network): No fixed drive, skipping.

Comment: I get: C:\Program Files\Chkdskall>ChkdskAll.exe
Drive C:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk successfully scheduled.
Drive D:\ (Type CDRom): No fixed drive, skipping.
Drive Q:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk for drive Q:\ is already scheduled.
Drive S:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk for drive S:\ is already scheduled.
Drive T:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk for drive T:\ is already scheduled.
Drive W:\ (Type Fixed): Chkdsk successfully scheduled.
However Q:,S: & T: won't run chkdsk at startup. Only C: & W: will do

Comment: Basically when launched it will schedule disk check for C: and that all other disks are already scheduled for check, however at boot only diks C: will be verified

Comment: ok sorry, I don't know why it isn't working for you